# Strange string in IE10 Address bar

Tags: razor, iis-7.5, internet-explorer-10

This question has been asked earlier and it does have a solution... but solution is not working for me.. 
[Strange string in IE Address bar and in source 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612124/strange-string-in-ie-address-bar-and-in-source)

The address in URL bar should be: http://site.com/CoupleofFolders/page.aspx 
instead becomes: http://site.com/(X(1)F(lnz3ovk89OA4AbMN4S-sYVZCgCULL))/Folders/Page.aspx

I'm having this problem only in IE10... 
 and this is happening only in the address bar and not in page code, which is creating linking problems...
I have added sessionState cookieless false to my webconfig as the answers states in the earlier question but that is still not changing IE10 behavior... 
webserver is Win2K8R2 IIS 7.5 & i'm using ASP.NET 4 WebPages2 Razor

any suggestions..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in ASP.NET's browser definition files. It's detecting IE10 as a version of IE that doesn't support cookies, so it switches to [cookieless sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx#cookieless_topic2) (even though you told it not to).

You can install patches for ASP.NET that corrects the issue, as documented in this [excellent Scott Hanselman post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx).

The TL;DR; version of the blog post is you need to [download a patch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088).